# apt-get upgrade gcc error

Tags: apt, gnome, upgrade, gcc

Every time i run this command

```
sudo apt-get upgrade gcc
```

i get this error[image]

[image]

i have tried

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

then

```
sudo apt-get update
```

it starts from beginning and got stuck at 33%.

how to solve this problem??

Edit:

I tried this link in browser and it doesn't work

```
https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/pool/main/wine-staging-amd64_2.21.0~xenial_amd64.deb
```

what to do now to upgrade gcc???

Comment: Not sure what 'got stuck at 33%' is about, nor how gcc is related to anything, because that's not at all what your screenshot shows. Read the 'ERR 17' line again carefully, then try that line's URL in a normal web browser.

Comment: It keeps showing 33% [working] and then gives me the error in the picture. I already tried the url in the browser and it  doesn't work. @user535733

Comment: So, remove that PPA. If the URL doesn't open, it doesn't exist or is down. That's the problem and nothing else according to what you're showing.

Comment: How to remove that PPA @MichaelBay

Comment: 1. The launchpad repositories often have a short lifetime. Suggest : Delete the winehq links from /etc/apt/** ( Or move the list to a backup folder.) 2. `gcc` cannot` be "upgraded". The system compiler is gcc, g++ version 5.4.0 : Never change or remove. 2a. You can have as many gcc versions as you want, installed at the same time. Default is `sudo apt install g++-4.7 g++-4.8 g++-4.9`

Comment: Alternatively at Settings > Software & Updates (Software Properties in 16.04), "Other software" tab. Find the line, select and remove.